finding the shortest distance using relative velocity
let v and r be the velocity and displacement vectors, at an instance considering 2 bodies A and B
$$r_A = 13i + 5j$$
$$r_B = 3i - 5j$$
$$v_A = 3i - 10j$$
$$v_B = 15i + 14j$$
the question asks, considering the relative motion of A with respect to B, find the shortest distance between the 2 bodies.
here`s my try on it,
$r_{AB} = r_B - r_A = (3-13)i + (-5-5)j = -10i-10j \\ 
v_{AB} = v_B - v_A = (15-3)i + (14+10)j = 12i+24j \\ 
|r_{AB}| = \sqrt{10^2 + 10^2} = 10 \sqrt{2} \\
|v_{AB}| = \sqrt{12^2 + 24^2} = 12 \sqrt{5}$
i stopped here because i had no idea how to continue, i asked the same question from gpt and it gave be some formula
$$d = \frac{|r_{AB} \cdot \hat v_{AB}|}{|v_{AB}|}$$
where $\hat v_{AB}$ is the unit vector of $v_{AB}$? and d is the shortest distance? he didn't elaborate on it and i didn't understand what he said.
can someone help me on finding the shortest distance

This answer provides a derivation for the time at which the objects are closest. From this the shortest distance is obtained.

Great start with breaking down the relative displacement and relative velocity vectors. Let’s go over the steps to find the shortest distance between the two bodies, A and B, using relative motion concepts.
Step 1: Define the Relative Position and Velocity Vectors
You correctly calculated:
Relative position vector rAB=rB−rA=−10i−10jrAB​=rB​−rA​=−10i−10j
Relative velocity vector vAB=vB−vA=12i+24jvAB​=vB​−vA​=12i+24j

Step 2: Determine the Direction of Closest Approach
The shortest distance between the two bodies occurs when their relative position vector, rABrAB​, is perpendicular to their relative velocity vector, vABvAB​. This condition means that there’s no movement toward or away from each other at that moment, only sideways motion.
To find the shortest distance, we use the following formula based on relative motion:
d=∣rAB⋅v^AB⊥∣∣vAB∣
d=∣vAB​∣∣rAB​⋅v^AB⊥​∣​
Where:
rABrAB​ is the relative displacement vector.
vABvAB​ is the relative velocity vector.
v^AB⊥v^AB⊥​ is the unit vector perpendicular to vABvAB​.


thank you for the explanation, i missed the key point where the distance is shortest when the final displacement vector and the velocity vector is perpendicular, but where did that formula come from$$d = \frac{|r_{AB} \cdot \hat v_{AB}|}{|v_{AB}|}$$

You have founded the position and velocity of B relative to A, the position and velocity of A relative to B is :
$r_{AB}=r_A-r_B=10 i+ 10 j$ is the initial position, is the position in t=0, it is assumed
$v_{AB}=v_A-v_B=-12 i-24 j$ is the relative speed, is constant $\forall t \geq 0$
Then A have rectilinear motion, its relative position
as a function of time is,
$r_{AB}(t)=(10 i+ 10 j)+v_{AB} t=(10i+10j)+(-12 i-24 j)t=(10-12t)i+(10-24t)j, \ \  t \geq 0 $
The shortest distance between A and B, d implies minimun $d^2(t) $ and $d^2(t)=||r_{AB}||^2=(10-12t)^2+(10-24t)^2$
Deriving to find critical points
$2(10-12t)(-12)+2(10-24t)(-24)=0 \Rightarrow t=\frac{1}{2}$
we can verify, in $t=\frac{1}{2}$ there is a minimun. Why?
Then the shortest distance is  $d=.... $
gpt is wrong Why?
EDIT
The formula for the shortest distance is $d=|r_{AB}.\hat{v_{AB}}|$ donde $\hat{v_{AB}}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to $v_{AB}$, Why?
because in the XY plane with center at B, the trajectory of A is a straight line $r_{AB}(t)=(10i+10j)+(-12 i-24 j)t$ and making a drawing we see that $d=||r_{AB}| cos \theta|$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $r_{AB}=(10i+10j)$ and $\hat{v_{AB}}$ and by definition of inner product $d=|r_{AB} cos \theta|=|r_{AB}.\hat{v_{AB}}|$

i understood that the distance is shortest when the velocity vector is perpendicular to the distance vector from the previous comments, so for shortest distance the dot product between the final displacement vector with t as a parameter and velocity vector should be 0, from that i can get t = 0.5, but where did the d=... equation that gpt gave me come from, can you please derive it?
